# Dependancy Injection of Google guice doesnt work in Scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

I want to use DI google guice which works perfectly fine in Java but doesnt work in case of scala. Here is my code:

**Module:**

```
class ConfigModule extends AbstractModule{
  override def configure(): Unit = {

  }

  @Provides
  @Named("config")
  def getConfig(): Config = {
    new Config
  }
}
```

**Config**

```
   class Config {
    val config1: String = "Sample"
   }
```

**Service**

```
class Service(@Named("config") config:Config) {
    
      def read(): Unit = {
        println("Reading")
      }
    
    }
```

**Main Class**

```
object SampleJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ConfigModule)
    val service = injector.getInstance(classOf[Service])
    service.read()
  }

}
```

**Error:**

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.job.Service. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.job.Service.class(Service.scala:7)
  while locating com.job.Service
```

Where am I mistaken?

UPDATE:

```
class Service(@Inject @Named("config") config:Config) {

  def read(): Unit = {
    println("Reading")
  }

}
```

This also returns the same error

```
Could not find a suitable constructor in com.job.Service. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.job.Service.class(Service.scala:8)
  while locating com.job.Service
```

Comment: `Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private` - you haven't annotated Service with `@Inject` even though it has a more-than-zero-argument constructor and no zero-argument constructors.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz for quick reply, but It still gives the same error after adding @Inject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you what happened:

```
Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private
```

So you need to add `@Inject` annotation... on *your constructor* like [in tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).

Instead of

```
class Service(@Inject @Named("config") config:Config) {

  def read(): Unit = {
    println("Reading")
  }

}
```

it should be

```
class Service @Inject() (@Named("config") config:Config) {

  def read(): Unit = {
    println("Reading")
  }

}
```